# How can I retrieve binary data using Mysql Python connector?

Tags: python, mysql

If I create a simple table in MySQL with binary data:

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( bar binary(4) )
INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES ( UNHEX('de12') )
```

Then try to read it using the MySQL Connector/Python:

```
import mysql.connector
conn = mysql.connector.connect(database='test', user='test')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM foo")
cursor.fetchall()
```

I get this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xde in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

I don't understand why the Python MySQL connector is trying to decode the column as UTF-8. I just want to get the raw binary data, how can I do this?

(Python 2.7.10, Mysql 5.7.22, MySQL Connector/Python 8.0.12)

Comment: `connection.set_charset_collation('latin1')` worked around it for me, for the dumb reason that latin1 will never have decode errors. Connector seems to have gone ignorant of BINARY data types.

Answer (score 2):

Use raw connection (or raw cursor) to execute the fetch.

```
import mysql.connector
conn = mysql.connector.connect(database='test', 
user='test',raw=True)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM foo")
cursor.fetchall()
```

By default, python fetch command tries to convert the binary data to a string. When it tries this, it encounters a byte sequence which is not allowed in utf-8-encoded strings. Setting raw mode to `True` overrides this behaviour and makes the results be returned as is, rather than converted to Python types.